# Cannot upload more than 50KB using Google Cloud Storage POST Object XML API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have created a form for uploading files to Google Cloud Storage using the POST Object XML API.

This works fine except for files exceeding 50KB. I have tested on Google Chrome and Firefox.

Here is the HTML

```
    <form id="upload-form"
          method="POST"
          role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">File input</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="file" class="filestyle"
                 name="file">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    $('#upload-form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("/experimental/upload/signed-url").then(function (info) {

            var form = $('#upload-form')[0];
            var formData = new FormData(form);
            formData.append('googleAccessId', info.googleAccessId);
            formData.append('policy', info.policy);
            formData.append('signature', info.signature);
            formData.append('bucket', info.bucket);
            formData.append('key', info.key);
            formData.append('success_action_status', info.successActionStatus);
            $.ajax({
                url: info.url,
                data: formData,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
            }).then(function (res2) {
                console.log(res2);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This endpoint /experimental/upload/signed-url creates responses like this one

```
    {
      "googleAccessId" : "xxxx",
      "policy" : "REDACTED",
      "signature" : "REDACTED",
      "successActionStatus" : "201",
      "url" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket",
      "bucket" : "my-bucket",
      "key" : "path/file-name",
      "clientName" : null,
      "publicUrl" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/path/file-name"
    }
```

The code that creates the signature looks like this

```
    try {
        byte[] policy = policyDocument.toJsonBytes();
        System.out.println(policyDocument.toJson());
        String encodedPolicy = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(policy);
        ServiceAccountCredentials cred = ServiceAccountCredentials
            .fromStream(new FileInputStream(googleCredentialsFile));
        byte[] signatureBytes = cred.sign(encodedPolicy.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
        String signature = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(signatureBytes);
        info.setGoogleAccessId(cred.getAccount());
        info.setPolicy(encodedPolicy);
        info.setSignature(signature);
        info.setSuccessActionStatus(STATUS_CODE);
        info.setUrl(String.format(END_POINT_URL_FORMAT, info.getBucket()));
        return info;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

And here is what the policy document looks like

```
  {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "success_action_status": "201"
      },
      {
        "bucket": "XXXXX"
      },
      {
        "key": "path/file-name"
      },
      [
        "content-length-range",
        0,
        1895825408
      ]
    ],
    "expiration": "2018-06-13T12:51:45.143+03:00"
  }
```

For files exceeding 50 KB, I get a HTTP status 400 with this body

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
   <Message>Invalid argument.</Message>
   <Details>Cannot create buckets using a POST.</Details>
</Error>
```

Is there anyone who can help me upload more than 50KB with this?

Comment: It seems that the POST method will only work with objects, not buckets. Look at the [list of methods](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-methods) of the XML API. You can use the PUT method to upload buckets, and for objects you can use POST. That's why you receive the `Cannot create buckets using a POST` error.

Comment: Are you defining the form action like: **<form action="http://BUCKET_IDNAME.storage.googleapis.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">** ? Maybe I'm missing something maybe but couldn't see it in your code. You also can see [an example on the Documentation to POST an object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object)

Comment: @Temu I have edited the question and added the HTML. I actually read the documentation and was even able to upload with the code above as long as the file did not exceed 50KB.

Answer (score 2):

I am with GCP Support. We were able to get the same error message using a POST request based on [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#usage_and_examples), independently of the file size.

It got fixed once we changed the equivalent to `"url" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket",` by adding the object: `"url" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/my-file.ext",`

Then using `POST` we kept getting some error messages so we changed the method to `PUT`. Then it worked.

Not working curl request:

```
curl -d @[FILENAME.EXT] @[JSONFILE.json] -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]' http://[BUCKET_NAME].storage.googleapis.com/
```

Working curl request:

```
curl -v H 'Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]' -F upload=@[FILENAME.EXT] -X PUT http://[BUCKET_NAME].storage.googleapis.com/[FILENAME.EXT]
```

I asked also to improve the documentation with the lessons learned.

Answer (score 0):

Make your file field the last field of the form i.e.

```
  var frm = new FormData(this);
  var file_path = uploadForm.get("file");
  uploadForm.delete("file");
  uploadForm.append("file", file_path);
  ajax.send(uploadForm);
```

Comment: How does that get around the 50KB limit?

Comment: This is specifically for GCP Buckets' case.